# java.lang.RuntimeException: Spurious serialisation error

Tags: java, runtime

I had problem with my client program when I run my client in eclipse or netbeans, I get a runtime error java.lang.RuntimeException: Spurious serialisation error. But when i use command prompt I have no errors.

### Here is my client code

http://pastebin.com/jUkw7F7k

---

Comment: You might want to cut down your code to something reasonable. (And perhaps try unit testing.) This exception is one that your code has thrown. More useful would be the exception trace from the original exception.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are writing an `Integer` (through autoboxing) to the serial file and attempting to read two objects casting them to `BigInteger`. (But see my comment on the question.)